# How to Select Dropdown by Value dom-repeat Dropdown

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, polymer, polymer-2.x, dom-repeat

I am trying to load back in dropdown settings after a page refresh in Polymer.  The dropdown loads dynamically from an AJAX call, and once the dropdown in set it is saved in localStorage.

```
  <select id="customer" on-change="selectCustomer">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Customer</option>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[customers]]" as="customer" index-as="index">
      <option value="[[customer]]">[[customer]]</option>
    </template>
  </select>
```

...

```
selectCustomer() {
  localStroage.setItem("customerName", this.$.customer.value = index;" 
)
```

I have tried

```
setDropdown() {
  // index generated in text matching for loop
  this.$.customer.selectedIndex = index; 
)
```

and

```
setDropdown() {
  // customerName generated in text matching for loop
  this.$.customer.value = customerName;
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a better way would be binding your dropdown value to the attribute `customer` then observe the value of `customer` and save it to the local storage ... sync it on `connectedCallback` [a demo is always the best way to explain](https://codepen.io/MWalid/pen/QQEpKM) ...